# cocos2dx (javascript)のBatchNodeについて

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x

cocos2dxの**Javascipt**版でブラウザ上のゲームを製作しています．

**SpriteBatchNode**を利用してDraw関数の呼び出し回数を少なくしているのですが，
AndroidやiOSからブラウザを開いてプレイしてみると，
画像は正しく表示されているものの，Draw関数のコール回数がまったく減っていません．

PCからプレイすると意図通りの動作が行われ，Draw関数のコール回数が激減しています．
（約3000→8）

BatchNodeはスマートフォンなどでは利用できないのでしょうか．